# Can the word “go” be used as a helping verb?

Tags: grammaticality, colloquialisms, collocation

For instance:

> “Go eat your dinner.”

It appears that the word *“go”* is being used as a helping verb. Is it being used a helping verb? If so, can *“go”* only be used as a helping verb in imperative sentences?

Comment: Nope, I want to go eat dinner now. [in fact, I do. :)] . Mother to child: Go eat your dinner now. I want to leave immediately. Mother to child: Leave immediately.  I don't want to play tennis. Husband to wife: Play tennis, don't complain.

Comment: "Go" is not grammatically a helping verb in standard English, but it serves the purpose of one.

Comment: 'Go get a life' and 'Go figure' are perilously close to a helping verb, I would suggest.

Comment: This is what's called a "Serial Verb Construction". Many languages use them extensively, but English limits them to verbs of coming and going, in several constructions: _Go get it, Go and get it, Come get it, Come and get it._ The ones with _and_ allow past tense, but the ones without _and_ don't: _He went and got it_, but not *_He went got it._

Answer (score 1):

It is a usage of the verb *go* that is followed by the 'plain form' (or bare infinitive form) of another verb. The idea is

> To move, travel, or proceed (to somewhere) so as to perform a specified action, or for the purpose of a specified or implied activity...(often with the sense of movement weakened)

(*Oxford English Dictionary*, OED)

The *OED* labels this usage as (nowadays) "colloquial" in North America and nonstandard in British English. It gives examples of this construction as far back as Old English. An example from Early Modern English comes from 1591, Edmund Spenser:

> Now thou maist go pack.

which means "Now you may go pack."

Jane Austen wrote in 1813:

> Your Streatham & my Bookham may go hang.

It is not always used as an imperative phrase, as

> You wanna go see a movie?

shows.

The same construction is also found in such "imprecatory phrases" (OED) as

> [go fly a kite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-fly-a-kite)
>   go take a flying leap
>   go jump in a lake
>   go f**k yourself

and even

> [go figure](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-figure)

---

NOTE also that in the USA (apparently not nowadays in the UK) we use the verb *come* in a similar fashion to idicate "an action or activity which is the consequence or purpose of movement," as these OED citations show:

from about 1375:

> He praide ȝou com speke wiþ him.

which means

> He prayed(?) you come speak with him.

And about 1616 (Shakespeare):

> Quicke, quicke, wee'le come dresse you straight.

(Quick, quick, we'll come dress you straight.)

and 2007:

> I have half a mind to call the men in white coats to come take you away.

(Tamar Myers, *Hell hath No Curry*)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me: There is a novel by Harper Lee (written long ago, but only recently published), *Go Set a Watchman*.

That title comes from the King James version of the Bible (Isaiah 21:6)... but note the punctuation:  *Go, set a watchman, let him declare what he seeth*.

So maybe *Go eat your dinner* should be punctuated as *Go, eat your dinner*.  That is: two separate clauses, connected by a comma.

Comment: Or "go and eat your dinner".

Comment: Yes, as a British English speaker I would say 'Go and (do X)'.