# Go and come as verbs and the ommitting of and

Tags: grammar, british-english, north-american-english, german

I have a question relating to the verbs "come" and "go" plus another verb. Why do americans say come sing with us (for example and not come AND sing with us (as is the norm in English English. Like with the verb go. Go speak to your friend (for example) and not go AND speak to your friend. Is this an influence of German or yiddish on American English, perhaps?

Comment: They say both, and, please, correct your spelling. Nationalities and languages are capitalized in English.  It is not the norm in BrE, either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the word “go” be used as a helping verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446272/can-the-word-go-be-used-as-a-helping-verb)

Answer (score -2):

The first verb is an imperative that could be its own sentence.  The usage is common enough that we omit punctuation.  Note that we never say "she came sang" or "he went spoke".